# ng2-select2 cannot select a particular option

Tags: javascript, angular, jquery-select2

I am using https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2 angular component to handle a pulldown that gets its data from a remote api.  The initial list of data that gets populated works fine and I have no problem selecting any of the options in the pulldown, but if I cause the select2 component to have to get data a second time from the api I am not able to select one of the items in the list of options and the previous selection remains selected.  Here is some screen show of what is happening.

- initial load

[image]
Here I select `dev1-access-est-1` and the screen looks like.

[image]

So far so good.

- Now I try to change selection to dhcp-hkg1-1-6

[image]

But when I click on dhcp-hkg1-1-6 the Filter Key value remains dev1-access-est-1.

[image]

Here is the template HTML I am using for the select2 component:

```
<div class="form-group__text ">
  <select2 name="cm_select2" id="cm_select2" [value]="filterKey" [options]="select2Options"></select2>
</div>
```

And here is where I am setting my select2Options:

```
  setSelect2Options () {
    this.select2Options = {
      'width': '100%',
      'minimumInputLength': 3,
      'ajax': {
        'url': function(params) {
          var d = new Date(),
              month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
              day = '' + d.getDate(),
              year = d.getFullYear();

          if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
          if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

          var startDate = [year, month, day].join('-');
          var url = "http://dev-03.example.com/api/v1/cm/cm_list/?cm_type=" + $( "#node" ).val() + "&start_date=" + startDate + '&source=mongo';
          return url;
        },
        'dataType': 'json',
        'data': function (params) {
           var query = { 'starts_with': params.term, 'page': params.page || 1 };
           // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&page=[page]
           return query;
        },
        'processResults': function (data) {
           var results = [];
           for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++ ) { results.push( { "id": i, "text": data.results[i]} ); }
           // Tranforms the top-level key of the response object from 'items' to 'results'
           return { 'results': results };
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try adding cache: false to the options

```
'ajax': {
        'cache': false,
        'url': function(params) {
          var d = new Date(),
              month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
              day = '' + d.getDate(),
              year = d.getFullYear();

          if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
          if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

          var startDate = [year, month, day].join('-');
          var url = "http://dev-03.example.com/api/v1/cm/cm_list/?cm_type=" + $( "#node" ).val() + "&start_date=" + startDate + '&source=mongo';
          return url;
        },
```

Comment: I looked at the issues for https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2 and I found this issue: https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2/issues/136 and it looks like https://github.com/hassegawa had fix but when I try to find the file ng2-select2.component.ts on my system I cannot find it.  I installed ng2-select2 as per the docs: `npm i -S ng2-select2`.

Comment: That fix is still waiting to be merged into master it seems. If so can you try to include that specific branch in your project by 

`npm i -s  git://github.com/rsliusarchuk/ng2-select2.git#fix-on-change-data`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem got worse with each access to the remote API.  On the second call to the remote API I could not select two options from the list.  I read the issue I pointed out in my comment above and realized that one cannot reuse `id`'s from one call to the backend API to the next so I decided to add the epoch time to each `id` in my `processResults()` function like so:

```
'processResults': function (data) {
    var results = [];
    const epochTime = (new Date).getTime();
    // work around for issue https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2/issues/136 (use epoch time to get unique ids.
    for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++ ) { results.push( { "id": i + epochTime, "text": data.results[i]} ); }
    // Tranforms the top-level key of the response object from 'items' to 'results'
    return { 'results': results };
}
```

If some finds a better solution please post it here.